# How to write unit tests for React Native's useEffect hook inside which I'm using navigation.addListener('focus')?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, jestjs

I've created a React Native component define below, and it's utilised as a navigation screen through the react-navigation library.

```js
const RecipeScreen = () => {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([])
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)

  const navigation = useNavigation()

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', async () => await loadRecipes())
    return unsubscribe
  }, [navigation])

  async function loadRecipes() {
    const response = await fetchRecipes() // does an API call
    if (!response.error) {
      setRecipes(response.recipes)
    }
    setError(response.error)
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.listContainer}>
      {error ? (
        <Error />
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          data={recipes}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Recipe {...item} />}
          keyExtractor={(recipe) => recipe.id}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  )
}
```

How can I write two unit tests, one for when the API call fails and displays the Error component, and another for when the API call succeeds and shows a list of recipes?

Comment: first extract the functionality inside useEffect to a function and test that function, no real need to write a test for the hook, it's vendor code. A small note that returning inside the useEffect represents a cleanup function for the component.

Comment: What's the point of the test - prove that useEffect works, navigation listeners work, or your API call works? All those are outside the code here and not worth testing imo